# JQuery Masonry - width variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

i'm using masonry (jquery) and it's all ok but i'm doing an option to "deactivate" masonry, i use this:

```
    function box(box_width) {
        if(box_width == 1) {
          $('#contenedor').masonry('option', { columnWidth: function() { return 550; }});
          $('#contenedor').masonry('reload');   
        }
        else {
          var gutter = 55;
          var min_width = 250;
          $('#contenedor').masonry('option', { 
            columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
              var num_of_boxes = (containerWidth/min_width | 0);
              var box_width = (((containerWidth - (num_of_boxes-1)*gutter)/num_of_boxes) | 0) ;
              if (containerWidth < min_width) {
                box_width = containerWidth;
              }
              $('.imagen').width(box_width);
              return box_width;
            }
          });

          $('#contenedor').masonry('reload');   
        }
      }
```

i have 2 buttons to send 1 or 2 to the function box(), the problem is when try to send "1", the if sentence don't load correctly, masonry do only 1 column (OK) but the images have the same width of the else sentence and i need to did the image more big

how can i do ?

pd: sorry for my english, i'm from spain!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are passing an integer or a string to the function. You should really be making sure the value passed is an integer also.

```
function box(box_width_str) {
        var box_width = parseInt(box_width_str);
        if(box_width == 1) {
          $('#contenedor').masonry('option', { columnWidth: function() { return 550; }});
          $('#contenedor').masonry('reload');   
        }
        else {
          var gutter = 55;
          var min_width = 250;
          $('#contenedor').masonry('option', { 
            columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
              var num_of_boxes = (containerWidth/min_width | 0);
              var box_width = (((containerWidth - (num_of_boxes-1)*gutter)/num_of_boxes) | 0) ;
              if (containerWidth < min_width) {
                box_width = containerWidth;
              }
              $('.imagen').width(box_width);
              return box_width;
            }
          });

          $('#contenedor').masonry('reload');   
        }
      }
```

Try that code, hopefully it works

Comment: @OscarGalindo I can't see anywhere in the first clause of the `if` statement that you are setting the width of any images, if you need to set the width then you will need to call it similar to the second clause of the `if`

Comment: @OscarGalindo Here's a thought actually, maybe the function is being called more than once. If the first call is anything other than `1`, then it will call the else statement, then if the next statement is `1`, then it will run the first clause and seemingly have also called the second. Put this at the start of your function: `alert(box_width);` and tell me how many times it comes up

Comment: the problem is when the columnwidth is setted to 550 the size of the image don't change